# Underlying DataStructure for HashSet

Tags: java

For ArrayList underlying dataStructure is Array, for LinkedList it is Link object and for HashMap or HashTable it can be an Array Of LinkedList or Tree, what is the datastructure used in HashSet

Comment: the jdk source is publicly available through the openjdk project, why not find the answer for yourself?

Comment: @jtahlborn it is not a play to dig with JDK source code, if you can play then why don't you answer it ?

Answer (score 6):

According to [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet%28%29) the backing data structure for a HashSet is a HashMap.

The JDK 1.6 code verifies this:

```
public HashSet() {
    map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The naïve idea of hashing is to store an element into an array at a position index computed as follows:

- obtain element_hash_code of the element by processing the element's
  data and generating an integer value (the idea of "hashing" the
  element roughly means "grinding it up")
- use a simple mod operation to map into the array's range

So these can be done by array or linked list.

In java the `HashSet` uses a `HashMap` internally

From the source code

```
public HashSet() {
    map = new HashMap<E,Object>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HashSet uses HashMap internally for storing the data. And I believe HashMap is an array of Entry objects.

A related post to understand the internal structure of HashMap:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596549/how-does-javas-hashmap-work-internally

Answer (score 0):

The underlying data structure of HashMap and HashSet (which is based on HashMap) is hash table http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table. In HashMap source code it looks like an array of Entrys

```
Entry<K,V>[] table;

... 

static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
        final K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K,V> next;
        int hash;
...
```